# System specifications for NGS data analysis

Tags: genome, ngs, transcriptome

I have a 3.7 GB whole genome data of a eukaryote, for which genome assembly, gene prediction, and annotation steps have to be performed. In some time I would also need to analyze the transcriptome data of the organism. Can someone please let me know what are the system requirements for carrying out the aforementioned NGS data analysis? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "3.7 GB whole genome data" what kind of data. sequencing? what platform? what tech specs?